# can java use tls.crt tls.key directly?

Tags: java, kubernetes, ssl

In Kubernetes, most of application are using tls.key and tls.crt in a secret.
But with java application running as POD, we have to convert it to PCKS12 or other keystore format.
Is it possible to use tls.key and tls.crt in java directly? even with some java source code?

The java application is a springboot based application.

Comment: "even with java source code?" for sure, but you may be happier with an `initContainer:` and an `emptyDir:` that converts into the PKCS12 you mentioned; what have you already tried?

Comment: Do you mean use openssl to covert? but that will introduce another container image in our application, which is not expected.

Comment: your original question didn't specify it must use the same container image as is currently in use, but if said image includes the jdk then you can still use an initContainer, and java as you said, to keytool those files into a keystore and then point your main containers at that emptyDir to use it. If you're asking if there's a kubernetes primitive to magically convert to java keystores, for sure no